# Use scanf to get commands and arguments in C

Tags: c, input, arguments, command, scanf

I need to create a method that get's commands from users using scanf and runs a function. The command can be simple as `help` or `list` but it can also be a command that has an argument like `look DIRECTION` or `take ITEM`. What is the best way to go about this? I could just loop through the characters of a single given string and check it manually but I was wondering there was a better way of doing this.

```
scanf("%s %s", command, argument);
```

This won't work if there's no argument. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Your [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is dangerous, since subject to [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Provide some [mre] in your question please.

Comment: Your question is not clear, since lacking some   [mre]. Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website.

Comment: BTW, **the C language has no methods.** Read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf). In C++ (not the same language as C) "methods" are called member functions. But [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) does have methods. So you will fail to create a method in C.

Comment: What you need, dear OP, is to scanf() something *safely* ( a challenge of its own) and then run a collection of `if( strcmp(command,"your_argument")==0) {..}`

Comment: Dear OP, I have posted a slightly long but (IMO) comprehensive answer to help you, based on the little i suggested in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

### There is a 'method' that may work. In fact, two come to mind.

---

Both rely on **whitespace chars** (in *plain-english*, `'\n'`, `' '`and `'\t'`) **separating the arguments** , and I assume this is good enough.

---

### 1

First, the relatively easy one - using **`main(int argc,char *argv[])`** as *most* CLI programs do.

Then, running a long string of `if()`s/`else if()`s which check if the input string matched valid arguments , by testing if `strcmp(argv[x],expected_command)` returns `0`.

You may not yet have been taught about how to use this, and it may appear scary, but its *quite easy* if you are familiar with `string.h`, arrays and pointers already.

Google searches and YouTube videos may be of help, and it won't take more than 20 or so minutes.

---

### 2

Second, if you have your program with a real CLU 'UI' and the program is in a loop and doesn't just terminate once output is generated - unlike say `cat` or `ls` , then you take input of 'command' strings *within* the program.

This means you will have to, apart from and before the `if`-ed `strcmp()`s , ensure that you take input with `scanf()` safely, and that you are able to take multiple strings as input, since you talk of sub-arguments like `look DIRECTION`.

The way I have done this myself (in the past) is as follows :

**1.** Declare a **command string**, say `char cmd[21] = "";` and (*optionally*) initialise it to be empty , since reading an uninitialised string is UB (and the user *may* enter EOF).

**2.** Declare a function (for *convenience*) to **check `scanf()`** say like so:

```c
int handle_scanf(int returned,int expected){
    if(returned==expected)
        return 0;
    if(returned==EOF){
        puts("\n Error : Input Terminated Immaturely.");
        /* you may alternatively do perror() but then
           will have to deal with resetting errno=0 and 
           including errno.h */ 
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        puts("\n Error : Insufficient Input.");
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Which can be used as : `if(handle_scanf(scanf(xyz,&xyz),1)==0) {...}`
As **`scanf()` returns number of items 'taken'** (items that matched with expected format-string and were hence saved) and here there is only 1 expected argument.

**3.** Declare a function (for *convenience*) to **clear/flush stdin** so that if and when unnecessary input is left in the input stream , (which if not dealt with, will be passed to the next place where input is taken) it can be 'eaten'.

I do it like so :

```c
void eat()
{
    int eat; while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
```

Essentially clears input **till a newline or EOF** is read. Since `'\n'` and EOF represent End Of Line and End Of File , and modern I/O is line buffered and performed through the `stdin` file , it makes sense to stop upon reading them.

**EDIT** : You may alternatively use a **macro**, for slightly better performance.

**4.** Print a prompt and **take input**, like so :

```c
fputs("\n >>> ",stdout);
int check = handle_scanf(scanf("%20s",cmd),1);
```

Notice what I did here ?

`"%20s"` does two things - **stops buffer overflow** (because more than 20 chars won't be scanned into `cmd`) and also stops scanning when a whitespace char is encountered. So, your main command **must** be *one-word*.

**5.** **Check if the the command is valid** .

This is to be done with the aforementioned list of checking if `strcmp(cmd,"expected_cmd")==0` , for **all** possible expected commands.

If there is no match, with an `else` , display an error message and call `eat();`(arguments to invalid command can be ignored) but **only** `if(check != -1)`.

If `check==-1` , this may mean that the user has sent an EOF signal to the program, in which case, calling `eat()` within a loop will result in an *infinite  loop* displaying the error message, something which you don't want.

**6.** **If there is a match**, absorb the whitespace separating char and then `scanf()` into a char array ( if the user entered, `look DIRECTION`, `DIRECTION` is still in the input stream and will only now be saved to said char array ). This can be done like so :

```c
#define SOME_SIZE 100 // use an appropriate size

if(strcmp(cmd,"look")==0 && check==0){ // do if(check==0) before these ifs, done here just for my convenience)
    getchar(); // absorb whitespace seperator
    char strbuff[SOME_SIZE] = ""; // string buffer of appropriate size
    if(handle_scanf(scanf("%99[^\n]",strbuff),1)==0){
        eat(); 
       /* look at DIRECTION :) */
    }
    // handle_scanf() generated appropriate error msg if it doesn't return 0
}
```

**Result**

All in all, this code handles `scanf` mostly safely and can indeed be used in a way that the user will only type , say :

```sh
$ ./myprogram
>>> look DIRECTION
    # output 
>>> | #cursor
```

If it is all done within a big loop inside `main()` .

---

### Conclusion

In reality, you may end up needing to use both together if your program is complex enough :)

---

*I hope my slightly delayed answer is of help :)*

*In case of any inaccuracies , or missing details, please comment and I will get back to you ASAP*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good way to parse an inputted string using strtok and scanf with a limit of 99 characters

```
#include <string.h>

char command[99];
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", command); //This gets the entire string and spaces

char *token;
        
token = strtok(command, " "); //token = the first string separated by a " "

if (strcmp(token, "help") == 0){
    //do function
} 

else if (strcmp(token, "go") == 0){ //if the command has an argument, you have to get the next string
    token = strtok(NULL, " "); //this gets the next string separated by a space
    if (strcmp(token, "north") == 0){
        //do function
    } 
}
```

You can keep using `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` until `token = NULL` signifying the end of a string

Comment: Your `scanf` is subhect to buffer overflow. What if the user types `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: And it would be better to *explicitly* represent [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your commands in memory (as pointers to some `struct`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know, but this is my first month of a C programming class in college and we're limited to only using scanf which I know will have buffer overflows but they explicitly said what the input was going to be so I know there won't be a buffer overflow. They told us not to worry about buffer overflows for now and honestly I have no idea how to stop them, from my research, scanf is not a good function to use.

Comment: Then at least add a comment about that issue in your code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I explicitly said I was using scanf. Is it possible to prevent buffer overflows using only scanf?

Comment: Yes, if you take several hours to carefully read the documentation of [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Notice that **the source code of `scanf` and of `strtok` is available in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and inside [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)**. Please download and study the source code of these libraries

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what makes you think a newb would do this ? or even *could* do this source-reading ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Maybe when I have time I'll take a look. I'm still a newbie to C and have a lot to learn about computer science in general so I'm not sure how much I would understand.

Comment: A newbie should be able to read documentation and books.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can certainly read it, but without background knowledge in a lot of subjects, its hard to understand it now but someday I will. I'm jealous of the generation that got to grow up during the digital revolution. Would've been cool to witness the technological advancements of computer science in person. Not to mention, it must've been easier to understand computers back then when they were much less advanced. Ironically now, we're learning backwards. We start off with high level languages and work our way down to the hardware. I wish I could've learned the other way around.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions

Comment: @Brandalf: it depends upon the programming courses you follow; IIRC professor Queinnec taught a course at Paris University "from the chip to the web"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I mean sources for implementation of std library functions

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch in light of your comments on this answer , would you like to take a look at my attempt at answering this , as and when you can ?